# Windows Azure Access Control and Windows Phone 8

Tags: azure, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, acs

I'm currently developing an app which has single sign on via Windows Azure Access Control Service. I am using the Access Control Service for Windows Phone NUGET package (the same control can also be found in the Windows Azure for Windows Phone toolkit).

I am just wondering if there is a new way of doing this in Windows Phone 8?

These current controls haven't been updated for about a year and a lot seems to have changed since then. I have searched but search engines still seem to be returning Windows Phone 7 results mostly.

Comment: In terms of Windows Azure ACS nothing has really changed in the passed year. Just JWT token was introduced. So a code written to work for ACS an year ago, shall be working now also. I'm not WP dev and have no idea about the differences between WP8 and WP7, but if you are good in WP dev most probably will be able to the stuff written for WP7 run on WP8. Technically and in terms of communicating with ACS - nothing has changed, so it just the UI and user interaction that might not work in WP8.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Also, one other question? Is ACS something that we can just use without ever having to scale? (Microsoft does it for us in the background). There's no mention of needing to scale anywhere.

Comment: Indeed, that's the case. Just use ACS and don't bother about scaling it. But all it does, is to provide an Identity Federation service. I don't think an Identity federation service needs much scaling capabilities. How many users may authenticate at the same time?

Comment: Brilliant, well not enough to worry about. We are still building the service from scratch at the minute. Another thing I have noticed though is that the tokens issued by ACS appear to only last for a day, is there a way to refresh the token?

Comment: you configure token lifetime in when you configure the Relying Party application. you can adjust that lifetime. Unfortunately there is no way to refresh a token when using Passive Federation - directing the user to some login page to authenticate.

Comment: astaykov, I would suggest converting your comments above into an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services (still currently in preview) has new functionality designed to help make user authentication easier. See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/